# MS ACCESS default and native images path

Tags: forms, image, ms-access, default

I have a form made through the wizard and i want to change the logo image with a ms-access default ones but when i try to change it via properties, it asks me for a path with a dialog box..
I want to use the default ms-access images/icons and i don't know their default path..

[image]

Comment: Review https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons

Comment: Should be able to find some clip art in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\CLIPART

Answer (score 1):

i find a location for office2016 images and icons files:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16

As i suspected, inside this folder there are some exe and dll files that contain the images i was searching for..

With an automated software, i extracted all the icons and images from exe and dll files.

Answer (score 0):

First,go to the property of this logo, change the image path & make him embanded.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! An answer should solve the problem as-is, so you should edit it in order to be more useful possible